# Publishing to a Facebook Page Wall - With Graph API?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to publish to the wall of a Facebook Fan Page, from a python/django web application.

The new Graph API looks nice and simple, so I'd like to use that.  Unless there is a much easier way :-)  I'm guessing the pyFacebook package would do want I want, but it appears to use the old rest interface.  pyFacebook is probably a complete overkill for something that I should be able to do in just a few lines of code with the Graph API.

Looking at the new Graph API, it appears that this should be really simple.  I've created an application, and I can publish to my applications wall with no problems.  However, my application doesn't appear to have permissions to publish to my Fan Page.  Any tips on how to enable this permission?  Or is there a much better way to do this?

Do I even need my own application to do this, or is there one out there that I can already use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your fan page allows wall posts from any user in its settings, your app should be able to just post to `<page_id>/feed`

If you are fan page admin and want to post on fan page's wall on behalf of the page itself (without showing your name), then read about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#impersonation) or in more details [here](http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/).

Comment: Does this still work? Facebook API look to change frequently and constantly.